# What's the difference between cbr0 vs vxlan in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

We have an K8S Cluster environment with `1 master node` and `2 worker nodes` and all are on Linux and we are using flannel

**Example is given below**

```
Master (CentOS 7) - 192.168.10.1

Worker Node-1 (CentOS 7) - 192.168.10.2
Worker Node-2 (CentOS 7) - 192.168.10.3

Worker Node-3 (Windows ) - 192.168.10.4
```

Now, we have to add a `Windows node` (eg 192.168.10.4) to existing cluster `192.168.10.1`

According to this [link](https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/windows/user-guide-windows-nodes/) it appears that we have to update `cni-conf.json` section of `flannel` from `cbr0` to `vxlan0` and to my understanding this is done to communicate with Windows

My question will this change (`from cbr0 to vxlan0`) break the existing communication between  Linux to Linux?

Answer (score 1):

### Let's start with definitions.

`cbr0` is own kubernetes bridge which is created to differentiate from `docker0` bridge used by docker.

`vxlan` stands for `Virtual Extensible LAN` and it's an overlay network which means it encapsulates packet into another packet.

More precise definition:

> VXLAN is an encapsulation protocol that provides data center
> connectivity using tunneling to stretch Layer 2 connections over an
> underlying Layer 3 network.
>
> The VXLAN tunneling protocol that encapsulates Layer 2 Ethernet frames
> in Layer 3 UDP packets, enables you to create virtualized Layer 2
> subnets, or segments, that span physical Layer 3 networks. Each Layer
> 2 subnet is uniquely identified by a VXLAN network identifier (VNI)
> that segments traffic.

### Answer

No, it won't break anything in communication between Linux nodes. This is an another option how nodes can communicate between each other using `flannel` CNI. I also tested this on my two nodes `linux` cluster and everything worked fine.

Main difference is how `flannel` will work with packets. It will be visible via `netstat` or `wireshark`, while for PODs nothing is going to be change because packets will be normalized when they come to PODs.

**Note!** I recommend testing this change on a small dev/test cluster as there may be some additional setup for `firewalld` (usual rule before making any changes on production).

### Useful links:

- [Flannel - recommended backends for VXLAN](https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/backends.md#vxlan)
- [Kubernetes Journey — Up and running out of the cloud — flannel](https://itnext.io/kubernetes-journey-up-and-running-out-of-the-cloud-flannel-c01283308f0e)
- [How Kubernetes Networking Works – Under the Hood](https://blog.neuvector.com/article/advanced-kubernetes-networking)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'll go through the links as well